# What does it mean to 'act upon' after memorizing all of the Quran?

Tags: quran, quran-memorization

When someone memorizes the whole Quran they will go to heaven.

But I read somewhere that only those who memorize the whole Quran and act upon it will go to heaven.

What does act upon it mean?

For example does it mean that I should do what the Quran tells me to do (don't gamble or drink alcohol...etc).

And does it mean that if I memorize the whole Quran I should share it to the world, for example lead people in prayer?

But what if i'm a woman? What can a woman who memorized the Quran do to act upon it?

Comment: To act upon something in English means to follow what it says, so yes, when scholars say "act upon the Qur'an" or put it into practice, this is what they're referring to, and that's something that can be done by both men and women.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try making this simple for you.

Is it really worth it to just memorize Quran and not act upon it.! Allah mainly sent the Holy Quran for our guidance, not just to read. Its purpose is lost if you only read it but act just oppositely.

Secondly, it doesn't matter whether you are a man or a woman, if you are Muslim, all the teaching are Farz (obligatory) upon you. If you read the complete Quran with translation, you may find your answer in detail. There are several verses for both men & women. *I am not mentioning all those verses because there are a lot of them and it would surely elongate the answer.*